# "Column is not iterable" error while calling a function from another imported notebook

Tags: python, azure, databricks

in notebook1

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import current_timestamp
def add_ingest_date(input_df):
output_df = input_df.withColumnRenamed("somecolumn", 
current_timestamp())
return output_df
```

in notebook2

```
%run "../common_functions/add_ingested_date"
final_df = add_ingest_date(input_df)
```

I get "Column is not iterable" error

Comment: Please provide sample of data your are passing in. Did you check for data types?

Comment: *Column is *not* iterable (end of post)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to change the name of a column with name 'somecolumn' to current_timestamp(). This is not proper. If you want to change column name you need to give a string not a function. For example:

`output_df = input_df.withColumnRenamed("somecolumn", "newColumnName")`

If you want to add a new column which shows current timestamp then you need to specify you are adding a new column to the data frame

`output_df = input_df.withColumn("somecolumn", current_timestamp())`

Comment: Oh damn! such a big typo. Thank you so much